# Set data to a label in Grid View

Tags: asp.net

I have a Grid view which is contain a label and wanna set a data(string) to this label in that grid view.here is my code:asp.net

```
     (Label)GridViewName.Rows[0].Cells[2].FindControl("Label_Name") = "sara";
```

But I receive an Error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label'
```

What should I do?

Comment: you can not assign string to label control.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set data to a label in GridView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24991068/set-data-to-a-label-in-gridview)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set Label's Text property like this:

```
Label Label_Name= (Label)GridViewName.Rows[0].Cells[2].FindControl("Label_Name");
if(Label_Name!=null)
{

  Label_Name.Text = "sara";
}
```