# Set data to a label in GridView

Tags: asp.net

I have a label in an asp GridView and I want to set bind data to it.

Here is my RowDataBound method:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    var name = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("Label_name");
    name.Text ="sara";      
    name.DataBind();
}
```

and here is my GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewCertificateType" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"   OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" >

<asp:Label ID="Label_name" runat="server" Text="" ></asp:Label>
```

But after  `name.Text ="sara";`, I receive this exception:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: No the answer of null did not fit here !, you should find the label when the data are binding and inside the binding loop. Where is the `e` ? Where are you call that function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your RowDataBound method, make sure you have a condition to check what the type of the row is. This event will be called for every row in your GridView, including header and footer rows. If `Label_name` is not found in the header row, you'll have a null object. Once you do that, get rid of `name.DataBind();`, as it is not needed.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var name = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("Label_name");
        name.Text = "sara"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: it's true, the label exist in your DataRow and not header row or footer row,then you should to check type of DataRow

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var name= (Label)e.Row.Cells[X].FindControl("Label_name");
name.Text ="sara";      
name.DataBind();
```

X means index of column

Comment: ok, check what object is null,"e" - "e.Row" - or name and tell us

Comment: and your column is a bincoumn or templatecolumn, and you want to change text of a label inside it or change text of cell ?